# EMC Design Precaution

Tags: pcb-design, layout, emc

I'm designing a simple circuit which will
charge a big capacitor for 3 seconds,
then pass a 5A current for few microseconds,
then charge again the big capacitor for 3 seconds,
then pump again 5A for a few microseconds, and so on.
And now I test it on a breadboard and I'm convince that its working. 
So I started to do a PCB layout.

[image]

Questions are the following:

1. Do I need to concerned on the EMI emission?
2. What design techniques can you recommend to me or PCB guide layout on this specific PCB.
3. Any precaution that I need to do in the circuit or even PCB layout?

Comment: Sharing your schematic will help formulate good answers. Also, is the circuit going to pass 5 Amperes "*for few Microseconds*" or "*for 3S*"? Contradictory information in the question.

Comment: Is 3s the repetition period of pulses?

Comment: It will pump 5A for few microseconds and this scenario will be repeated after 3S.

Comment: It will better if you can explain more about the schematic. Could include a capture of the schematic?

Comment: What is the different between 2nd and 3rd question?

Comment: What's the fuction of the pin in the upper left corner? And what is the drive or the amp?

Answer (score 3):

1.- Yes, sure. You always must attend the EMC performance of your electronics design.

EMC or Signal Integrity, we are talking about the same. Although probably It's a hobbyist-project and you won't need to pass an emission or immunity EMC test in a EMC Lab but EMC is also the noise, the crosstalk or ground bounce and this could be a problem inside your project.

So, yes. For emission you can check: (only a summary)

- Raise/Fall Time in high speed signals.
- Layout of high speed. (Changes of layers, loop current...)
- Possible antennas. (Your connector and your cables could work as an antennas)

2.- It would better if you explain us more about your circuit.

I suppose there is a component that works as a switch. The out of this component we can call it "switch node". In this node the voltage is

$$V = L (di/dt) $$

; V is voltage, L the inductance of the node, i is the current, and $$di/dt$$ is the rise time (or fall time) of change.

This parameter is really important!

Maybe you can:

- Decrease the rise time. (Could it work slower?)
- Decrease the voltage (Could you use a lower voltage?)
- Decrease the inductance in your switch node.
- Include a snubber (a circuit for absorb the voltage peak).

3.- This question is the similar to 2 isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Some additional tips for PCB design in EMC point of view:

- **Try to keep conductor loops as small as possible** (usually can be followed when using optimized and short conducting routes). See: [Electromagnetic induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Faraday.27s_law).
- **Try to avoid 90 degree "corner" turns in PCB conductors** as the signal may "bounce" in tight turns -> can cause EM-interference. Good way is to use 45 degree turns.
- **Do not use too narrow conductors** especially in power line conductors (VCC etc.)
- **Try to have good ground (GND) plane and grounded in multiple points** -> reduces EM-interference
- **Use EM-radiation against itself**: keep forwarding and returning current conductors next each other -> cancel out each others' EM-fields.

Comment: Good points, except 90 degree corners [aren't usually that bad](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/bigbadbend.htm). It's probably not worth the effort to round off/chamfer most corners.

Comment: To add to wha @Justin says, my experience is 90 degree bends are no problem up to 1 GHz or so. Also, isn't your 5th bullet item the same as your first bullet?

Comment: No they are not. In the first bullet the point is to keep area inside a conductor loop small -> induces smaller voltages from outer EM-fields.
In the 5th bullet point is  that in a conductor flows current that creates EM-field. In returning conductor approximately same amount of current flows and their EM-field sum together -> zeroing each other's EM-field.